# Text Embedding result based on Priority

Tags: openai-api, embedding, word-embedding, opensearch, text-embedding-ada-002

I am new to OpenAI, I have integrated text-embedding-ada-002 modal in AWS OpenSearch for the semantic search.

I want text Embedding Results based on my priority order so for example
my document is like,
{
title: “random”,
desc:“random”,
}
if i search for “abc” word then if my priority order is title > description > etc… then it should be in order of that findings

So if two document found, one document is got because of “abc” is found similarity in description and another got because “abc” is found similarity in title. So, In the Results, first should be that document which got because of title is matched irrespective the order of document in database

This is just an example there would be lots of fields…

any solution ?

also another problem is if exact match found then also score is about 0.7, I think it’s low

I want embedding results based on my priority.

Comment: In OpenSearch, you can use the "function score query" or "boosting" to manipulate scores based on your field priorities.

Comment: @JeyhunRashidov This is my query 

query: {
                    knn: {
                        embeddings: {
                            vector: embedding,
                            k: limit,
                        },
                    },
                },

In this If i want to give priority to title how can i add boosting to title field because here embedding is a vector with large dimension which is created by OpenAI text embedding